# porque visual studio code se cierra solo o pierde el code run

Tags: vscode

Buenas a todos hace pocos días mi VSC empezó a no encontrar la extensión code run, la cual borro y vuelvo a instalar y cambio la configuracion de la terminal, se acomoda un rato y después vuelve a darme el mismo error.
A veces si estoy manipulando mucho sale un error de que se cerro todo y si quiero volver a abrir.

Errores que me salen "El host de extensiones finalizo inesperadamente" y "command 'code-runner.run' not found"
Uso windows 7.

Si alguien conoce una solución que sirva.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola!, puedes poner los errores que te da?. Puede que algo se te este pasando?. Que SO estás utilizando?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola lamentablemente me salen los dos mensajes juntos no son distintos problemas, mas detalles no tengo.